# Repeated or recurring

Tags: differences, computing

Can the word "recurring" and "repeated" be used interchangeably in the context of tasks such as habits, periodic reviews, etc..? for things that are repeated every day, or just once a week, once a month, etc.. the idea is that they are repeated at some point in time.

Example sentences:

> My agenda contains the following recurring tasks: *list of tasks*

> My agenda contains the following repeated tasks. *list of tasks*

Comment: If you have an answer, please write an answer. "Add a comment" is not for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, they're interchangeable but shouldn't the comparison be between recurring and repeat*ing* tasks?

Either way, there's a slight chance 'recurring' might refer to tasks which have recurred in the past, do so now and will in future while even more than 'repeating', tasks 'repeated' might refer to tasks cropping up again now, with little or no suggestion that they will do so in future.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say - there is a sense of inherent repetition in *recurring*, whereas *repeated* might be a matter of happenstance or externally driven. There's a reason things recur.

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer: either**

In the context of the question (if I understand it correctly), my subjective opinon is that both *recurring* and *repeated* would be acceptable to describe somethin such as a meeting that is scheduled for the first Friday of each month.

**General reasons for preference for *recurring***

My own preference would be for *recurring*, the, perhaps subconcious, basis for which is usage in other contexts where the words are not interchangeable. In these circumstances:

1. The sense of *repeat* is restricted to replication (duplication, triplication etc.) whereas that of *recur* implies *continuality*, although not necessarily infinitely so (as the initial version of my answer may have suggested).
2. The verb *repeat* is more commonly (although not exclusively) used transitively (e.g. “I repeated the password”)  rather than intransitively, whereas the verb *recur* is only used intransitively (“the event recurs“), which is the adjectival sense used in the question.

**Examples**

I am biological chemist rather than a mathematician, but have had some contact with information science. So the examples I give are not intended as mathematical definitions, but English usage, albeit technical.

Nevertheless, at the outset I would emphasize that this usage is not at odds with one of the (US) English definitions of *recur* in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recur):

> 4 : to occur again after an interval : occur time after time
> *the cancer recurred*

1. As a child learning mathematics in Britain I was taught that the decimal representation of one-third (0.3333333…) is spoken of as “nought point three recurring”, and this was at the time general British usage, and is still so according to the [BBC Bitesize GCSE (school qualification) Revision Guide](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zsy7pbk/revision/4).

> “A recurring decimal exists when decimal numbers repeat forever.”

(This is different from the three repeated occurrences of the digit 7 in a decimal fraction 0.4427778.)

2. In computer programming, recursion involves a specific form of repetition. In his comment @jimm101 does indeed reflect the common definition that “Recursion refers to algorithms that call themselves”, but a generally comprehensible aspect of this technical statement is that recursion involves a repetition of programming statements *in a regular manner*.

As a molecular biologist I am familiar with what are called [repeated sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_sequence_(DNA)) in the genomes (total DNA) of organisms. At its simplest one can represent a very short repeated sequence in a stretch of DNA (or indeed a computer string) as the upper case letters in the following:

```
atgcaggaGAATTCttcgaaattGAATTCcctagc
```

One could argue that the sequence GAATTC *recurs* in this string, but such (longer) sequences are found irregularly distributed through the genome (more on some chromosomes than others, and with different distances between them) which is probably why they are referred to as *repeating*, rather than recurring sequences.

**Conclusion**

I would maintain that recursion is a particular type of repetition, and, being appropriate to the example given, would make it the better choice.

Comment: I think you mean repeating, not recursion. "Non-terminating decimals that repeat are referred to as repeating decimals. Although they have an infinite number of digits, all of the digits in a repeating decimal are known. Also, to be considered a repeating decimal, the repeating digits cannot all be zero." Math.net (https://www.math.net/non-terminating-decimal#:~:text=Non%2Dterminating%20decimals%20that%20repeat,digits%20cannot%20all%20be%20zero) Recursion refers to algorithms that call themselves. A recursive algorithm can result in a repeating decimal, or almost any other type of output.

Comment: @jimm101 The answer, although incomplete, as the poster clearly recognises, is correct in all it says. The link you give is to a site that is low level and unreliable. I have therefore compensated for someone's downvote.

Comment: @Anton I don't think the answer is correct in all it says. Recursive traversal over a linked list normally isn't infinite. Infinite recursion is typically a bug not a feature. If the intention was to talk about repeating, then it's closer to addressing the question. As it stands, High Performance Mark is correct.

Comment: @jimm101 You may be right if talking about specific features of computing but the question (and this answer) are not about such restricted theme. The person who answered prefaced by say "At least..." We should take that as an invitation to see the answer as a partial answer, a contribution to reaching an answer, not as one to negate.

Comment: @jimm101 First I apologize for posting a quick incomplete answer when I had not time to follow it up properly. I have now done that and would regard my usage of terms as correct. I think there may be a British/US difference in describing decimal fractions as MW defines a recurring decimal as a repeating decimal, a term not used in British teaching as the BBC link bears out. Ultimately the intention of my answer is to try to indicate the differences between two apparently similar words in the English language and the psychological basis for a native speaker's choice.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark — I think it is an answer to the question now that I have revised it.

Comment: @Anton Thank you for your defence regarding recurring decimals, which I now document. I think there may be a difference between US and British usage. I apologize for posting an incomplete answer. It is now probably rather overkill.